# Maps Android Studio no se muestra cuando la app es descargada de play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-api

Estoy teniendo un problema al mostrar google maps en mi app, antes se mostraba correctamente el mapa, el marcador con el acercamiento solicitado, cuando emulo mi proyecto en el emulador o lo hago en mi celular a través de cable, el mapa se muestra correctamente, pero ahora que subí mi app a play store, el mapa no se muestra en los dispositivos que la descargan desde allí.

tengo configurada la credencial en GoogleApi desde hace varios meses, ahora he generado una nueva clave y la agregué al proyecto pero aun no me muestra el mapa.

Cuando solicité la primer clave en GooleAPIs mi proyecto tenía un nombre de paquete distinto al que ahora tengo y no estoy seguro si esta sea la razón, he buscado en GoogleAPIs la configuración del proyecto para cambiar el nombre de proyecto pero no me lo encuentro, tambien quisiera saber si creando un nuevo proyecto en GoogleAPIs esto se podría arreglar.

A continuación les muestro el archivo java, el xml y unas capturas de GoogleAPIs, agradezco su ayuda.

JAVA

```
public class Fragment_Rutas extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public Fragment_Rutas() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rutas, container, false);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return v;
    //AIzaSyBfIvrguKAhUaW8CA0dvgyEXEFADleNCtc
}

@Override//acercamiento
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    LatLng bogota = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bogota)
            .title("Uniagustiniana"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bogota, 16.1f));
}
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#94dea7">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Imagen de la actividad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen GoogleAPIs, credenciales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cuando emulo mi proyecto en el emulador o lo hago en mi celular a
>   través de cable, el mapa se muestra correctamente

**Recuerda que la Keystore que usas para debug no es la misma que se usa para firmar una aplicación para producción.**

Obten el SHA-1 del Keystore con el cual firmaste tu aplicación para la Playstore y habilita la API en la consola para el paquete de tu aplicación, con esto debe funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El API Key para debug no es el mismo que el que se define para una aplicación destinada a la Play Store.**

Comment: gracias, esto no me lo mostraba, pero le agregué una restricción de clave para aplicaciones android, escribo el nombre de paquete, pero me dice que la huella digital es obligatoria, como si yo tuviera que escribirla...

Comment: Puedes encontrar el nombre del paquete en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml. A continuación, usa el comando siguiente para obtener la huella digital:

keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore, donde uso este comando?

Comment: Accede a linea de comandos y existe un keytool dentro de el folder donde tienes instalado android studio \jre\bin

Comment: Si ya lo conseguí, @Jorgesys muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Un placer Alfredo, saludos! @IvanAlfredo

Comment: una vez hecho esto en la API consola, no debo hacer nada en mi proyecto de android studio, subir un nuevo apk a playstore y actualizar?

Comment: @IvanAlfredo La API KEY obtenida debe estar definida en el .apk que será subido a Google Play Store.

Comment: he seguido los pasos pero solo me muestra el mapa en el emulador, tambien cree una nueva clave y le asigné el sah-1 hoy y actualicé y desde play store no actualiza el mapa, en la estructura del proyecto al lado del fichero google_maps_api.xml(debug) muestra debug, o será que debo hacer todo de nuevo incluyendo el layout donde se muestra el mapa.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72599/discussion-between-ivan-alfredo-and-jorgesys).